# Magento place order button not visible

Tags: magento-1.9

I have just configured everything needed to reach the last step of the checkout method, but the place order button is not visible.

What is wrong?

I am using magento 1.9.2. and no extensions or modules.

[image]

Comment: Please check qty. or this one out of stock ?

Comment: Possible to add more info with front end and back end screen. this issue for all products on arrived ?

Comment: See updated question

Comment: check your checkout.xml for one step checkout. http://allabouttodd.com/story/magento-checkout-missing-place-order-button-final-step-one-page-checkout

Comment: On suggestion first U have add patch or not. if not add patch file for updates.